# Convert 2D numpy array into 3D numpy array with 3rd dimension

Tags: numpy, reshape

I have a numpy array of 2D shape

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
            [7,8,9,10,11,12],
            [13,14,15,16,17,18]])
```

and trying to convert into 3D shape of dimension `(3,3,2)` i.e,

```
np.array([[ 1,2,3],
          [7,8,9],
          [13,14,15]])
```

in 3rd dimension with index 1 and

```
np.array([[4,5,6],
          [10,11,12],
          [16,17,18]])
```

in 3rd dimension with index 2.

I tried to reshape as a.reshape`(3,3,2)` and getting this

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]],

       [[13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]]])
```

Any suggestions to convert this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html):

```
a.reshape(3,2,3).swapaxes(0,1)
```

output:

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 7,  8,  9],
        [13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6],
        [10, 11, 12],
        [16, 17, 18]]])
```